# Создание Batch.bat на создание папок

Tags: cmd, командная-строка

Необходимо решить:

Моя директория: `C:\test`

> Написать batch скрипт, который создает 3 папки, вложенные одна в
> другую.
>
> Папка верхнего уровня с именем 1, в нее вложена папка с именем 2, и в
> нее папка с именем 3.
>
> Для решения использовать цикл реализованный при помощи оператора
> безусловного перехода - GOTO, а также условие, ограничивающее
> количество итераций цикла (чтобы не создалось папок больше, чем
> требуется).

пока есть такое решение:

```
label1
increment somevalue
mkdir dir{somevalue}
cd dir{somevalue}
if somevalue<3 goto label1
```

Comment: Использовать %random% для наименования, а создавать вложенность при помощи прибавления папки к пути?

```set mypath=%mypath%/%random%```

Comment: использовать имя например name1, name2, name3

Comment: попробуй так: ```set /A COUNTER=%COUNTER%+1```

Comment: ничего не происходит

Comment: Используй рандомное число, если не хочешь продолжать возиться с этим. (не правильный ответ)